# Xbox 360 XNA HLS Streaming

Tags: xna-4.0, xbox360, aac, http-live-streaming, mpeg-2

I am interested in creating a simple HLS Viewer for the Xbox 360 that works kind of like [SilverLive](http://www.fatattitude.com/software/software-about-silverlive.aspx). I have read about as much documentation oh HLS that I can find and am not sure where to continue. I feel like I could probably write the code to handle HLS myself, it doesn't sound overly complex (unless there is something I am missing). I do not however, have any idea where to start with playing the video/audio segments on the 360 once they get there.

What does everyone think? Would I need to implement some sort of codec pack and use that to render the frames as a texture? If so, are there any functional codecs supported by .NET for mpeg2 and aac that don't use anything the 360 has no support for?

Comment: If you intend to release this on XBLIG, just note that there is no way to connect to the Internet, so streaming isn't doable.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I wasn't developing the app for myself and am not sure what it's intention was. I'm not doing it anymore however, but I'll keep this useful information in case I ever need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately XNA Framework games are not able to access the Internet (or perform any network communication at all other than through Xbox LIVE or System Link), so creating a streaming application isn't possible.

What you want to achieve *is* possible using the [professional development tools](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/xbox360/registereddevelopers), but your game/application wouldn't pass the certification requirements for release on the Xbox 360 (because of its use of the Internet/LAN).

Comment: Okay, so my old client's request was impossible as I posited. On to my second question, how would I go about playing a video created with mpeg2 and aac?

Comment: @CuddleBunny Unfortunately you would have to convert your video to WMV9, then use [`VideoPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.videoplayer(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx).